# PHP Round-Robin Ad Campaign Display

Tags: javascript, php, algorithm

I need to split ad revenue between two ad campaigns so that each page request serves only one campaign at a time and each time it's called, displays the next campaign. I would like to avoid pseudo-random.

For example:

```
Request 1: Ad 1
Request 2: Ad 2
Request 3: Ad 1
Request 4: Ad 2
...
```

What is the best way to accomplish this using PHP?

Comment: How is each url called? Are they two php files or one? Isn't it as easy as saying `header("Location: url-1")` in the url-2 file and `header("Location: url-2")` in the url-1 file?

Comment: Can this be done with an array or list? Ideally it would be a single self contained php file. The urls rotate every time someone opens the php file.

Comment: See the [latest update to my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35930271/2518200). Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: What are trying to accomplish here? Do you want a round-robin to AB test?

Comment: Everytime someone, anyone requests the file? That is not possible unless you add state of some sort, most likely a database.

Comment: This would make a split ad revenue between two ad campaigns which are usually posted on social networks.

Comment: You probably don't want to do it with redirects then. It would be easier to do this with a pseudo random number which would probably serve ads equally over time.

Comment: What do you mean by pseudo? Can you weight 50% with a random function?